# PySpark - How to calculate earliest timestamp for each row?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1fe2 | 2022-4-21 | 2020-9-12 | 2022-3-2 |
| 3gef | 2021-5-22 | 2019-3-4 | 2022-4-2 |

I am using PySpark. I have this dataset and I want to calculate the earliest timestamp for each row along with the column's name. For example,

result for 1fe2 should be "B" and "2020-9-12"

Comment: see [`least()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.least.html#pyspark-sql-functions-least) function

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
columns = ["ID", "A", "B", "C"]
data = [("1fe2", "2022-4-21", "2020-9-12", "2022-3-2"), ("3gef", "2021-5-22", "2019-3-4", "2022-4-2")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

// first concat the col name to the value

for col_name in (df.schema.fieldNames()):
    if col_name != "ID":
        df = df.withColumn(col_name, F.concat_ws(' ', F.col(col_name), F.lit(col_name)))

// then least() on each row

df.select(df.ID, F.least(df.A, df.B, df.C)).show()
```